# Gson ignore unknown enum value

Tags: java, gson

Is there a way to configure gson to ignore an unknown enum value? For
example

in my client code there is an enum DeviceType  has 2 enum value : PC,
MOBILE

But when a server is sent another type for example MAC as another
DeviceType. How can I configure my gson deserilalizer to set the
DeviceType = null instead of throwing an exception?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: If you don't know legal values, maybe you shouldn't be using enums? Or, conversely, if values are fixed, whoever sends bad values should fix their code not to send them?

Comment: The values are a fixed set per version. This doesn't change very often but a few one can be added in a new version. This is handle very nicely with protocol buffer, the parser just ignore that value and set into unknown fields. I wish gson provide something like that out of the box.

Comment: You probably should then just use a String, and helper method later on to get an Enum, if necessary. Also, if Gson did support set methods (not just fields), you could do conversion there... but it does not (yet?)

Answer (score 6):

Now we can use nullable enum type, for example:

```
data class SomeDTO (
    val type : DeviceType?,
    //other values
)
```

In that case, there won't be any exception in parsing.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily write a custom `JsonDeserializer` that ignores unknown values. Read more [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#custom-serialization-and-deserialization).
For a starting point, have a look at the source gson source code, class `com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters.EnumTypeAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the [source code](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/62a97023852f879eb5819c3ef0fb7e7fdda51bc7/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/TypeAdapters.java#L795), Gson does exactly what you want.

So your exception should come from another place. Look closely at your stack trace (or post it here) and you'll probably find out an NPE in your own code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure if this would work, but you could possibly declare a `static T valueOf(String)` method on your enum to override the default implementation with one that returns null for unknown values instead of an IllegalArgumentException.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) suggests the overriding static implementation would be used.

Then it just depends on how Gson handles the results of that method (assuming Gson even uses that method for parsing), but it's an easy workaround that could be worth a shot.

Comment: No, this won't work. Because (1) static methods are not overridable (the doc suggests about `Enum.valueOf(Class, String)` vs. `CertainEnum.valueOf(String)`, and (2) because Gson uses `name()` and `@SerializedName` internally. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/62a97023852f879eb5819c3ef0fb7e7fdda51bc7/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/TypeAdapters.java#L775-L784

Comment: Wow that is some a-level nitpicking. While not technically "overrideable" the method would be hidden and effectively overridden in this example which is what the docs explicitly say is possible, I even called out that I didn't know how gson worked and it was clearly suggested as an easy workaround that would take literally 30s to test with no guarantees. But thanks for coming in and commenting on a 4.5 year old answer that wasn't even selected and demonstating your knowledge of a technology that could have easily changed in 4.5 years.